# test for comparing the size of the treatment effect?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, t-test, experiment-design, group-differences

I am analyzing experimental data and would like to know the most appropriate approach.

For sake of simplicity, the setup can be described as follows: the data is for students who are either high-income and low-income, and there are two treatment conditions: whether students are monitored during an activity in which they are given some resources to share, and whether they are assigned to a partner who is high-income vs low-income. I want to see if the effect of monitoring on the amount shared is bigger on high-income vs. low-income students. In other words, I'm not comparing just the means (which would be a t-test, or I could use a regression if using controls) but I'm comparing the *difference*, or how *responsive* high vs. low-income students are to the monitoring treatment. What would be the appropriate statistical test for this?
Thank you!

Comment: You say "magnitude of change". What is the sequence of condition assignment - are students only observed once based on a randomly assigned dyad based on levels of Low-Low, Low-High/High-Low, High-High? And what is the hypothesis?

Comment: Yes, it's an activity under which either they are monitored or not. Maybe "magnitude of change" is not the best word, but rather something like comparing the size of the treatment effect (monitoring) for low-income vs. high-income students. I'm interested in looking at if either group is more responsive to monitoring than others.

Comment: This sounds like a moderator, or interaction effect, analysis. This can be done using various flavors of regression, or anova.

Comment: Does the focal student make the decision to share with the paired student unilaterally? What is the range of the outcome, [0,1] or [0,100] or [0,x<infinity]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me a critically missing aspect of the analysis is the correlation between pairs. You say:

> ...whether [students] are assigned to a partner who is high-income vs low-income.

implying that the "partner" is as much a part of the design as the student under observation.

The dyad structure of analysis reminds me of a wonderful paper from [Carlin, 2005](https://academic.oup.com/ije/article/34/5/1089/645923). Since these data are paired you simply can't ignore this aspect of the design. To be shared with requires one to share with others. So if you are deriving some response variable Y="material aquired" which may be negative if you gave more than you got, you can define: $Y^*_i = Y_{i,1} - Y_{i,2}$ for the $i$-th dyad where student 1 and 2 are paired together. Similarly you can define $X^*_i = X_{i,1} - X_{i,2}$ as the income difference between student $1$ and $2$ in the same dyad. Then you can fit a *regression through the origin* to test the hypothesis that sharing is associated with income. Since monitoring $M_i$ (1=Yes, 0=No) would occur at the dyad level, you can further test the interaction by including the product term *without main effect in a linear regression*:

$$ E[Y^* | X^*, M] = 0 + \beta X^* + \gamma X^*M$$

The hypothesis $\gamma = 0$ would test whether monitoring *moderates* the relation between sharing and income.

Answer (score 0):

If "amount shared" is a continuous variable, then you can at least start with ordinary least squares regression, where "amount" is the dependent variable and income and treatment are independent variables, and you also include the interaction of income and treatment. The interaction can be gotten by multiplying the two independent variables.

If "amount shared" is a bounded variable ranging from 0 to 1, then you might look into beta regression.